# Measuring inserts/second on a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm making a database right now to store values and i need to know how fast it can take data, how many inserts/second it can perform. I've been looking around and i've found a away to measure how many selects it can make but nothing about inserts. Are there any easy ways of doing this?

Comment: how hard is it to do something like `$start = time(); ... do inserts ...; $end = time(); echo ($end - $start) . " seconds";`?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987004/insert-random-data-in-mysql-and-php-for-benchmark